# Does mac resolution setting affect watching 4k videos?

Tags: display, imac, video, screen, resolution

I always use a 2020 27' iMac (5k screen) in the mode of scaled resolution 2048*1152 (<4k) with larger text so as not to exhaust my eyes. (System default is 2560*1440, also <4k, and it can go up to 3200*1800 with very tiny text.)

But does this affect the quality of watching 4k videos? Can the screen smartly play videos at its full strength or not?

I think this is a well-defined technical question and hence I don't need answers like 'try if you notice any difference'. And I was surprised that the comments have so far remained to be largely irrelevant to a real answer.

Comment: Which scaled resolution are you using?

Comment: @Theologin 2048*1152

Comment: Are you talking about Full Screen, or in a window? Either way, try it: see if you notice.

Comment: @benwiggy full screen

Comment: 4k is 3840 x 2160 so you're scaling anyway. Your screen is commonly referred to as 1440p, not 4k. By the same definition, 4k is 2160p. 4k, rather irritatingly after years of referring to screens by their h\*w pixel count, is actually [just under] 4,000 pixels *wide*.

Comment: @Tetsujin It's a 5K display, scaled to 1440p. (I wish Apple just used the scaling factor instead of 'looks like....'.)

Comment: At Full Screen, 4K is going to up-scaled, e.g. the screen is bigger, so the video will be zoomed in, with calculations to make it fit. Whether those calculations are different, or noticeably different, I don't know.

Comment: @benwiggy Sure, 5k>4k and probably some up-scaling, but it's not of my concern. I think my question is on a different side.

Comment: As it's a 5k screen [info edited in after my last comment] then it's going to be scaling whichever way you set it. You can't display 4k on it without scaling one way or the other. As to which is going to be sharpest, you'll have to try it & see.

Comment: @xiaohuamao Well normally, your Mac will automatically scale 4K videos to your screen's resolution.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question?